# Using BERT Embeddings + Standard ML for text classification

Tags: classification, natural-language, word-embeddings, transformers

I am trying to automatically detect whether a text is written by a Machine or a Human.

My first approach was using a TF-IDF to build features for a logistic regression classifier, where I got an accuracy of around 60%.

Now, I'm trying to obtain the features from BERT, as it was suggested [suggested](http://aclanthology.lst.uni-saarland.de/2020.acl-main.164.pdf) that it can be a good predictor.

I did so without fine-tuning the model, but the results of the logistic regression after using BERT are very bad - around 45%, i.e worse than a dummy classifier. This is my code so far (I am doing it in batches since I get GPU OOM message if I try to pass everything at once):

```
batch_size = 200
k = (training_set['document'].count() + 1)//batch_size + 1
results = []
for i in range(1,k):
  print("Batch "+str(i)+" out of "+str(k-1))
  current_batch = training_set.iloc[(i-1)*batch_size:i*batch_size]
  # Tokenizing with lambda function
  tokenized = current_batch['document'].apply((lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True,max_length=512,truncation=True)))
  # Padding
  # Padding will be very simply finding the largest document and then filling all the smaller documents with zero to have a square matrix
  largest_size = 0
  for document in tokenized.values:
      if len(document) > largest_size:
          largest_size = len(document)
  # Padding
  padded = np.array([document + [0]*(largest_size-len(document)) for document in tokenized.values])

  # Create Mask for where the padding was added to pass it to the model
  attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)


  # Execute Model
  input_ids = torch.tensor(padded).to(device)
  attention_mask = torch.tensor(attention_mask).to(device)

  # Run forward on the Neural network
  with torch.no_grad():
      last_hidden_states = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
  # Concatenate the results:
  for element in last_hidden_states[0][:,0,:].cpu().numpy():
    results.append(element)
  # Clean Cuda Cache
  gc.collect()
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

My training set is a pandas dataframe whose columns are [id,document,label] and my code for the logistic regression classifier is very straightforward:

```
features = results
labels = training_set['label']
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels)
lr_clf = LogisticRegression()
lr_clf.fit(train_features, train_labels)
lr_clf.score(test_features, test_labels)
```

Comment: I am not sure if that will help with your problem, but it might make your life easier. You can use pipelines for feature extractions:

```
pipe =pipeline('feature-extraction', model="seyonec/SMILES_tokenized_PubChem_shard00_160k", tokenizer="seyonec/SMILES_tokenized_PubChem_shard00_160k")
features = pipe("CCC")
```

Comment: I thought feature extraction was only the BERT model's word embeddings? Aren't those the features of the model to be fed to the Logistic Regression?

Comment: No it is the last hidden state. "Feature extraction pipeline using no model head. This pipeline extracts the hidden states from the base transformer, which can be used as features in downstream tasks."
You can also confirm that the activation are the same when using the pipeline or the model without the last layer:
model_features= torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.children())[:-1]))

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment, where did you take the quote from? I thought the outputs of the last hidden state would be the features, and what BERT does is feature extraction. Is this idea totally wrong?

Comment: yes my bad I was wrong. But the quote is from the documentation.